# Xamarin.Forms Invalid File Name When Compiling for Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have no idea what causes these errors.

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(3,3): Error APT0000: res/drawable-v21/avd_show_password 2.xml: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.] "avd_show_password 2.xml: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]". (APT0000) (SQLite_vs_CSV.Android)

/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(3,3): Error APT0000: res/layout/notification_media_cancel_action 2.xml: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.] "notification_media_cancel_action 2.xml: Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]". (APT0000) (SQLite_vs_CSV.Android)
```

I don't think it's related to my code because these files were not modified by my program. If any files need to be posted let me know.

Comment: `avd_show_password 2.xml` try removing space in name of file

Comment: These are default files, though. There really shouldn't be an error with them. I'm just curious as to whether the issue is on Xamarin's part or my own.

Comment: @Suraj likely has the answer here. Maybe there shouldn't be a problem with whitespace in the title of the file, but this is obviously the issue based on the error you posted: **Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]**